# Racket - How to use foldr to evaluate if any element in a list satisfies an argument?

Tags: recursion, racket, fold

I have the task of writing a program called `any?` that requires an input of a list and one-argument procedure and then tells you if any element in that list satisfies the procedure.

ex: `(any? odd? (list 2 4 6 8))` -> false

I need to use foldr in the program.

```
(define (any? procedure list1)
  (foldr (lambda (x y) (if (procedure x) true (any? procedure y))) false list1))
```

This is what I have so far, but when I run the program on `(any? odd? (list 2 4 6 8))` I keep getting an error saying "foldr : third argument must be a list, given false". I think this is because the base case of empty becomes the boolean false, which then is substituted for y, which is invalid since you need a list to run the recursive call.

Can someone help me go through the thought process to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foldr` handles the recursion for you; you shouldn't be calling `any?` again inside of the `lambda`. Instead, the false branch can just be `y`.

Or, a bit more obviously, perhaps:

```
(define (any? procedure lst)
  (foldr (lambda (x y) (or (procedure x) y)) #f lst))
```

Additionally, the error you're getting is because inside of the `lambda`, `y` is a boolean value. You're then passing it in as the second argument to `any?`, where you're expecting a list. Sadness results.

Comment: Thanks! I'm reading more about fold and I can't believe I didn't see that part